# How to set lockout duration to 0 by using command for windows?

Tags: command-line

Need your help, thanks in advice.

For some reason, I need set the lockout duration to never / 0 for some Windows servers by using powershell or command.

I find the command to set lockout duration, but it's not able set to 0. If I set to 30, it shows successful, but when I change 30 to 0, then it get error.

Is there any command can use for that?

```
    C:\Windows\system32>    net accounts /lockoutduration:30
    The command completed successfully.
    
    
    C:\Windows\system32>    net accounts /lockoutduration:0
    System error 87 has occurred.
    
    The parameter is incorrect.
```

Comment: You cannot set the lockout duration to 0 minutes. In reality, setting it to 0 would result in the account being disabled.

Comment: The author isn't attempting to disable the lock screen.  They are attempting to set the duration between invalid attempts to access an account (i.e. account lockout).  The URL in question has nothing to do with the author's problem and I see it as a shameless plug for a website.  **The duration between attempts cannot be zero.** If the duration is set to 0 it means the account is locked

Comment: I suspect the reason for the error is due to prevent you from effectively locking and disabling every account on the device.

Answer (score 0):

> I find the command to set lockout duration, but it's not able to set to 0. If I set it to 30, it shows successful, but when I change 30 to 0, then it displays an error.

This is because the minimum amount of duration is 1 minute. The reason it's allowing you to set it to 30 minutes is that the value is greater than the `Reset account lockout counter after` policy.

> The available range is from 1 through 99,999 minutes. A value of 0 specifies that the account will be locked out until an administrator explicitly unlocks it.  If the Account lockout threshold is set to a number greater than zero, the Account lockout duration must be greater than or equal to the value of the `Reset account lockout counter after` policy setting.

Source: [Account lockout duration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/account-lockout-duration)